# Permutation of arrays

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

There are multiple sets of elements like:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I need an algorithm to get all possible combinations of each element from each set.
E.g.

```
['a', 'e', 'g']
['a', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'f', 'h']
['a', 'f', 'i']
['b', 'e', 'g']

...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to solve this:

```py
def get_perms(arr): 
    def backtrack(idx, partial_res, res): 
        if idx == len(arr): 
            res.append(partial_res[:]) 
            return  
        for i in range(0, len(arr[idx])): 
            partial_res.append(arr[idx][i]) 
            backtrack(idx+1, partial_res, res) 
            partial_res.pop() 
    res = [] 
    backtrack(0, [], res) 
    return res
```

A quick test:

```
arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

get_perms(arr)
[['a', 'e', 'g'],
 ['a', 'e', 'h'],
 ['a', 'e', 'i'],
 ['a', 'f', 'g'],
 ['a', 'f', 'h'],
 ['a', 'f', 'i'],
 ['b', 'e', 'g'],
 ['b', 'e', 'h'],
 ['b', 'e', 'i'],
 ['b', 'f', 'g'],
 ['b', 'f', 'h'],
 ['b', 'f', 'i'],
 ['c', 'e', 'g'],
 ['c', 'e', 'h'],
 ['c', 'e', 'i'],
 ['c', 'f', 'g'],
 ['c', 'f', 'h'],
 ['c', 'f', 'i']]
```

The algorithm just goes over each inner list and adds each element to `partial_res` and calls itself recursively while incrementing the index to go to the next inner list.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Cartesion product. Use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product

matrix = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
for res in product(*matrix):
    print(list(res))
```